# Missing CSS and JS files In magento2 Git Repository

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I have Successfully Install the Magento2 But when I try to run Homepage I getting below Errors in the console.
[image]

Then I have checked in Magento git Ripo `https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/master/pub/static`

I have found the below Image All Folders are missing.

If some has that folders then please provide us...
[image]

Comment: Y down vote. the directory are missing if you have data then please provide me

Comment: My concern is that Magento2 git repo is not up to date.

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes also. This is a legit question. Here is a +1 to compensate. I will provide a possible solution in a few minutes.

Comment: I think other users are not read the whole question and don't understand what I have try to said

Comment: @KeyulShah - look on the plus side, the down vote enabled you to get that hat :D I will also +1 to compensate.

Comment: @KeyulShah I cannot understand why you are so worried about making question active even you got answer cannot expect this things from a reputed people like you.Sorry if I was rude.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The repo is up to date.
Here is how the resources in pub/static should work.
The meaning of "module" changed in magento 2. Now the files are not separated between code, template and skin. Everything goes in the same module `Vendor_Module`.

When requesting a resource from `pub/static`, if the file does not exist the request is rewritten to `../static.php?resource={resource name here}`.
Take a look at the `.htaccess` file in the pub/static folder to understand better.

You get 404 responses probably because you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled.
You should enable it.
But it can work without it.
There is a 'cache' system for these static resources.
<strike>navigate to the folder `dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View` and run this in the command line</strike>

```
php deploy.php
```

**[EDIT]**
In the later versions there is no more `dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View` folder.
You can get the same effect by running this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**[/EDIT]**

This will copy the static resources from each module to the `pub/static` folder.
Be patient, it will take a while.
Remember this for the future. It is recommended to do this on the live server. It will speed up the access to static resources.

But there is a catch.

If you modify one of the static resources inside a module, the changes will not be available until you run `php deploy.php` again.
And you should never modify any file from `pub/static` directly. The changes will be overwritten the next time your execute `deploy.php`.

Comment: After Enabling rewrite_module It will working Nice :)

Comment: running deploy.php from command prompt did the job, thanks again

Comment: @marius,  mod_rewrite enabled in my system and pub/static folder does not contain css and js  also  View folder does not  exits indev/tools/Magento/Tools/  .Then please please tell why  css and js not show 404

Comment: @AmitBera. This was an old answer. In the mean time the way the static files are deployed has changed. See my edit.

Comment: Nice explaination @Marius.it Works Thanks again.

Comment: is this answer still valid for merchant beta release??

Comment: I tried above solution but still got same error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
Go to Magento root path `xampp/htdocs/project`
and run this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`